# Box height is not as desired size in smaller devices- css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I'm facing an issue in matching the size of a  box to mobile(using bootstrap)
I have got 3 boxes, number 1 and 2 are images and number 3 has text,
and it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvbP4.png)

when I resize the screen to mobile size this is what happens(box number 3 is higher or in some devices shorter than box number 2, like here:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlr5R.png)

I need it to look like that (box number 3 in the same height as 2):[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS0Tg.png)

I tried to set max height and min hight to box3 but this is not the solution because it doesn't match to all the devices.

html:

```
 <section id="carousel-section">

  <div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="row feature">
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-8 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
             <div class="carousel-margin">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel1 slide container-carousel" data-
 ride="carousel1">
  <!-- Indicators -->
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>

 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="images/dragon_hunter_pic.png" alt="dragon_hunter_pic" 
   id="mainImage1" >
</div>

 </div>

    </div>
         </div>   
         </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 ">

       <div class="women-margin">
  <img src="images/women_3.png" alt="live" id="women-eyes1" >
            </div>
            </div>




  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 ">

      <div class="yellow-box">


      <h2 id="change_h2">THE DRAGON HUNTER</h2>
            <br/>
            <p id="change_p"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
       adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
        dolor aliqua. </p>

         </div>


      </div>

  </div>
 </div>

  </section>
```

this is the problematic box, box number 3:

```
    <div class="yellow-box">
```

css:

```
  .yellow-box{
 position: relative;

 display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

    min-height: 204px;
 margin-top:150px;
background-color: #e6ff00;
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;  


   }
```

this is box number 2:

```
  .women-margin{
  margin: -1px -15px -2px -17px;
position: relative;
display: block;
padding-right: 0;
   }
```

Comment: Please show us your code. We can't help you if you don't show us what you tried...

Comment: sorry, added code

Comment: I guess I can try using flexbox? If you want me to.

Comment: yes It will help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Nested Rows and Columns</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 /* Some custom styles to beautify this example */
    .main-content{
  min-height: 330px;
        background: #dbdfe5;
    }
    .sidebar-content{
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        background: #b4bac0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Open the output in a new blank tab (Click the arrow next to "Show Output" button) and resize the browser window to understand how the Bootstrap responsive grid system works. -->
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
                <div class="main-content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
                <!--Nested rows within a column-->
                
                        <div class="sidebar-content"></div></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="sidebar-content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Try this code.. for more info [click here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php)

Comment: this is not what I need, I need box number 2 3 to be under 1 in mobile and in desktop to be next to number 1

Comment: Now see that snippet

Comment: in desktop box 2 and 3 need to be ---next--- to number 1 .  in mobile boxes 2 and 3 need to be ---under-- box number1

Comment: For desktop use col-lg-4 for three boxes.. if you want ipad device screen use col-md-4. for more reference refer boostrap grid option..

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Nested Rows and Columns</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    /* Some custom styles to beautify this example */
    .main-content{
        min-height: 330px;
        background: #dbdfe5;
    }
    .sidebar-content{
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        background: #b4bac0;
    }
    .left{
        background: red;
    }
    .box2{
        background: green;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .box3{
        height: 100%;
        background: blue;
    }
    .right{
        background:green;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="carousel-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row feature">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-8 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 left">
                <div class="carousel-margin">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel1 slide container-carousel" data-
                 ride="carousel1">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>

                         <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                              <img src="images/dragon_hunter_pic.png" alt="dragon_hunter_pic" 
                               id="mainImage1" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="right col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 box2">
                   <div class="women-margin">
                      <img src="images/women_3.png" alt="live" id="women-eyes1" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 box3">
                    <div class="yellow-box">
                        <h2 id="change_h2">THE DRAGON HUNTER</h2>
                            <br/>
                            <p id="change_p"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                       adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
                        dolor aliqua. </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think this the only solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343344/make-two-side-by-side-divs-of-equal-heights