# make two side-by-side divs of equal heights

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, web-frontend

This is my final layout [image]

I want to keep the left column height same as the right one. I am simplifying my html so would be easy for you.

```
<div id="graphsWindow" style="height:100%; ">
<div class="table" style="height: 100%">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; height:100%;">

   <div style="border:groove; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-right:2px; border:groove; height:100%" class="col-md-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9" style="padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:15px; height:100%">                
   </div>

</div>
</div>
```

The div with class **col-md-2** contains the picture, the prev/next buttons and the list with check boxes

The div with class **col-md-9** contains the graphs and the buttons, labels at the bottom.

I have not specified a fixed height any where inside. How can I make the two divs of equal height?

### UPDATES

**Default Popup Window**

[image]

**Maximized Window**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With bootstrap-4, For equal height columns use `row-eq-height`

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: 1px solid grey;">.row.row-eq-height &gt; .col-xs-4</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: 1px solid grey;">.row.row-eq-height &gt; .col-xs-4<br>this is<br>a much<br>taller<br>column<br>than the others</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: 1px solid grey;">.row.row-eq-height &gt; .col-xs-4</div>
          </div>
```

Ref: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

add this css if you are using bootstrap 3

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.row-eq-height{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i realize now that i am using bootstrap v3.0 :)

Comment: ok. with or without row-eq-height the behaviour remains same. i.e if i maximize my window then the height expands as wanted but if the window size is small it does not fill the height. updates in my question

Comment: yeah write the same in media queries also. it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159211/discussion-between-znaneswar-and-samra).

Comment: No display:flex did not make a change

Answer (score 1):

I use of jquery, i hope help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var col9Height = $('.col-md-9').height();
  $('.col-md-2').height(col9Height);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to get this.

`height:100%` normally doesn't do much.

since you don't have any other divs(like nav or footer)

You could use:

`min-height: 50vh;` for each

You made need to play with it a bit, but I would remove the height: 100% everywhere, and add a `min-height: 50vh;` to each row div.

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.

If you need another strategy, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

My final markup is

```
<div id="graphsWindow" >
<div class="table" style="height:90%">
    <div class="row " style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; height:100%; ">

        <div style="border:groove; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-right:2px; height:100%" class="col-md-2">
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-9" style="padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:15px; height:100%">
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

which is exactly what i needed but when the window is **not maximized** the two divs are again of different height.